# Ionic 2: typescript: typescript: Cannot find name 'EventStaffLogService'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having this error. I've installed the latest app scripts. I don't know much about typescript but this used to work before I ran the update scripts.

**cli**

```
$ ionic serve

Running 'serve:before' npm script before serve

> ionic-hello-world@ watch C:\Users\cmadmin\Development\mobile\sportsinfocus-mobile-app
> ionic-app-scripts watch

[14:01:26]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.42
[14:01:26]  watch started ...
[14:01:26]  build dev started ...
[14:01:26]  clean started ...
[14:01:26]  clean finished in 6 ms
[14:01:26]  copy started ...
[14:01:26]  transpile started ...
[14:01:32]  typescript: ...sportsinfocus-mobile-app/src/app/events/event-sign-in/event-sign-in.component.ts, line: 18
        Cannot find name 'EventStaffLogService'.
event-sign-in.component.ts
```

**event-sign-in.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventStaffLogService, EventStaff } from '../shared/';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'event-sign-in.component.html',
  providers: [EventStaffLogService]
})
export class EventSignInComponent {
  eventStaff: any;
  eventStaffLogs: Object = { data: [] };
  fetchingLogs: Boolean = true;
  isSignIn: Boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private navParams: NavParams,
    private eventStaffLogService: EventStaffLogService,
    public toastController: ToastController
  ) {
    this.eventStaff = navParams.get('eventStaff');
    this.getEventStaffLogs();
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the issue. Seems that importing from an `index.ts` file causes this error.

changed my code from:

```
import { EventStaffLogService, EventStaff } from '../shared/';
```

to

```
import { EventStaffLogService } from '../shared/event-staff-log.service';
import { EventStaff } from '../shared/event-staff.model';
```

and it worked.